# Capture error to table instead of file- C# script task SSDT-2013

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

may anyone please help me to modify the below code. i am trying to capture error in table of database instead of file.

The Present code is writing error to log table, how can we modify to write the same error to table.

code

```
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    // Create Log File for Errors
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString()
                        + "\\" + "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    }

                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
```

Please share your valuable suggestion if it is possible.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would move the sql object creation to before the try, or else you will need to repeat it in the catch block, its up to you.

```
                ConnectionManager ConMgr = Dts.Connections.Add("ADO.NET:SQL");
                ConMgr.ConnectionString = "data source=database;initial catalog=zzzz_PRC;integrated security=true;persist security info=True;";
                ConMgr.Name = "DBConn";
                ConMgr.Description = "DBConn";
                SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)
                (Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
```

Next just run the query instead of logging to a file:

```
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                        string query = "Insert into " + SchemaName + ".logtable (Logtextcolumn) "; -- change tablename and columns desired.
                        query += "VALUES('" + exception.ToString() + "')";
                        SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }

            }
```